# Disable Right-Click for ContextMenuStrip in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a DataGridView with a dgv1.CellClick.

The context menu shows up with the cell is clicked with the left mouse button.  When this happens it also sets the position to the current cell BUT the contextmenustrip also shows up when I click on the RIGHT mouse button.  I want to disable or hide the context menu when the right mouse button is clicked.

I have tried:

```
    private void dgv1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            cms1.Hide();
    }
```

and this did not work.

Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    private MouseButtons e_Button = new MouseButtons();
    private void dgv1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        e_Button = e.Button;
    }

    private void cms1_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e_Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
            e.Cancel = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with this:

```
private void dgv1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)  {
        if ((e.Button != Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)) {
            cms1.Show(datagridview, e.Location);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That makes it show up with both buttons pressed anywhere in the grid.  I only want it to show up on the DataGridViewButtonColumn when the left mouse button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
}
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that it is a DataGridViewButtonColumn

Comment: you want to disable on contextmenu on datagridviewbutton

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dataGridViewExample_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response but that didn't have any effect.

Comment: have you tried it on EditingControlShowing DataGridView event?

Comment: @Scott you are sure that ContextMenuStrip property of DataGridView are none?